Conditional Transform in excel
How can I transform a row in excel based on condition using formula.
Like here three column A, B, C. If a column contain yes then the name of the header add to the activities column in a new row. Here example
Before:
name    | A     | B       | C
name1   | yes   | yes     | no
name2   | no    | yes     | yes
name3   | yes   | no      | no

After:
name    | Activities
name1   | A
        | B
name2   | B
        | C
name3   | A

now write formula

Look for questions on here asking about transpose or index with match.

It will helpful for me if you provide any resource, thanks

The resource is on here so you can look for q&a using the words I suggested.

"now write formula"... You might want to rephrase this line a bit.

=LET(y,B2:D4="yes",HSTACK(TOCOL(IFS(y,A2:A4),2),TOCOL(IFS(y,B1:D1),2))) or do you need the names as blanks in case of repeats?

If you need it to include blanks in case of repeated names:
=LET(y,B2:D4="yes",a,TOCOL(IFS(y,A2:A4),2),HSTACK(IF(XMATCH(a,a)=SEQUENCE(ROWS(a)),a,""),TOCOL(IFS(y,B1:D1),2)))
Where IFS is used to create an array returning the name of the row where the value in range B2:D4 equals text yes. Else it returns an error.
Wrapped in TOCOL with argument 2 (skip error values) returns the flattened names of the array.
Same logic is used for the header values.
To not repeat the name values, we perform XMATCH on the calculated names array. This returns an array of the position the name is first found within the array. If that position equals the sequence of the rows of the array it returns the name, else a blank.
Else:
=LET(y,B2:D4="yes",HSTACK(TOCOL(IFS(y,A2:A4),2),TOCOL(IFS(y,B1:D1),2)))

Edit to include a solution for older Excel, which isn't as straightforward as in Office 365:
For the names:
=IFERROR(TEXTJOIN(,,IF(AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW($B$2:$D$4)-ROW($B$2))*COLUMNS($B$2:$D$4)+COLUMN($B$2:$D$4)-COLUMN($B$2)+1/ISNUMBER(LEN(IF($B$2:$D$4="yes",$A$2:$A$4,NA()))),ROW(A1))=(ROW($B$2:$D$4)-ROW($B$2))*COLUMNS($B$2:$D$4)+COLUMN($B$2:$D$4)-COLUMN($B$2)+1,IF($B$2:$D$4="yes",$A$2:$A$4,NA()),"")),"")
For the header titles:
=IFERROR(TEXTJOIN(,,IF(AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW($B$2:$D$4)-ROW($B$2))*COLUMNS($B$2:$D$4)+COLUMN($B$2:$D$4)-COLUMN($B$2)+1/ISNUMBER(LEN(IF($B$2:$D$4="yes",$B$1:$D$1,NA()))),ROW(A1))=(ROW($B$2:$D$4)-ROW($B$2))*COLUMNS($B$2:$D$4)+COLUMN($B$2:$D$4)-COLUMN($B$2)+1,IF($B$2:$D$4="yes",$B$1:$D$1,NA()),"")),"")
I think both need being entered using ctrl+shift+enter (array formula).

what is supported excel version for these functions ?

Office 365 (and maybe Excel 2021?)

@mestu are you using the latest licensed version?

i'm using professional plus 2019 licensed version

@mestu I added an edit to include a solution for older Excel. You really need to mention your version in your post if it's not the latest, else posted answers may be good, but not working for you.
